# Weight Paint not working with some objects

Tags: armature

Just finished armature of a hand and posing is glitching a bit so I needed to weight paint parts of the object that I wanted to "move" with the main object (hand). The paint is refusing to be on the object.I wanted to select more paint onto metacarpus (between thumb and index finger)but it just doesn't want to pain on that object
[image]

Comment: Looks like there is not enough geometry: weight is a property of vertices: if you have no vertices you'll have no paint. Add more subdivisions or loopcuts.

Comment: It works now, thanks.